# The href and click event listeners should be executed sequentially

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, django, django-templates

I'm working on a Django project in which I need to move to a specific URL and then toggle the sub dropdown menu, but the issue is that both things are happening at the same time.

Here is my dropdown code

```
<a href="{% url 'my_applications' %}"
           class="nav_link {% if request.resolver_match.url_name == "payroll_941_files" %}active{% endif %}  dropdown-btn"><img src="{% static 'application/img/icon_doc.svg' %} "><span
                class="nav_name" >My Applications</span> </button>
                <div class="row dropdown-container ">
                    <div class="col-md-2">
                        {% for company in companies %}
                            <a href="{% url 'my_applications_id' company.id %}" class="company-row" >{{ company.name | title }}</a>
                        {% endfor %}
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Here is my Javascript code

```
var dropdown = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-btn");
    

    for (var dropdown_size = 0; dropdown_size < dropdown.length; dropdown_size++) {
    dropdown[dropdown_size].addEventListener("click", function() {
        console.log(dropdown.length);
        this.classList.toggle("active"); 
        var dropdownContent = this.nextElementSibling;
        if (dropdownContent.style.display === "block") {
        dropdownContent.style.display = "none";
        } else {
        dropdownContent.style.display = "block";
        }
    });
    }
```

Now when I click the My application dropdown section both href and toggle running simultaneously.

Comment: `preventDefault`

Answer (score 0):

You could use a prevent default event listener in order to avoid this.  [This](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_preventdefault.asp) guide from W3 schools explains what that is and how to use it. Hope this helps!

Comment: Actually, what I want is for the page to move to the url after clicking on the My application and then toggle the submenu.